# Sending string (of characters) to active window

Tags: c++, c, x11, keyboard-events

I wrote a simple program that reads the characters from external device (bar code scanner) from serial port (/dev/ttyS1) and feeds it to the currently active window (using XSendEvent).

Program works fine on faster computers, but on slow ones the situation happens (very often) that characters don't get received in the same order they were sent. For example, scanner sends 1234567 to serial port, my program sends char events 1234567, but the active program (xterm for example) receives 3127456. I tried calling XSync in various places and adding *usleep* calls, but it did not help.

Does anyone have an idea how to force the "order" of characters?

Or is there some other way to send a string to the active window (I don't even mind using an external program if needed)?

Here's the code, perhaps I'm just doing something wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>  // serial port stuff
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

/*
    BarCode KeyboardFeeder: BCKF
    Copyright (c) Milan Babuskov
    Licence: GNU General Public Licence

    Compile with: g++ bckf.cpp -lX11 -L /usr/X11R6/lib/ -o bckf
    Keycodes:  /usr/X11R6/include/X11/keysymdef.h
*/
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void SendEvent(XKeyEvent *event, bool press)
{
    if (press)
        XSendEvent(event->display, event->window, True, KeyPressMask, (XEvent *)event);
    else
        XSendEvent(event->display, event->window, True, KeyReleaseMask, (XEvent *)event);
    XSync(event->display, False);
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool sendChar(int c)
{
    if (c >= 0x08 && c <= 0x1b)     // send CR twice
    {
        sendChar(0xff0d);
        c = 0xff0d;
    }

    printf("Sending char : 0x%02x\n", c);
    char disp[] = ":0";
    char *dp = getenv("DISPLAY");
    if (!dp)
        dp = disp;
    else
        printf("Using env.variable $DISPLAY = %s.\n", dp);
    Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(dp);
    if (dpy == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR! Couldn't connect to display %s.\n", dp);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        Window cur_focus;   // focused window
        int revert_to;      // focus state
        XGetInputFocus(dpy, &cur_focus, &revert_to);    // get window with focus
        if (cur_focus == None)
        {
            printf("WARNING! No window is focused\n");
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            XKeyEvent event;
            event.display = dpy;
            event.window = cur_focus;
            event.root = RootWindow(event.display, DefaultScreen(event.display));
            event.subwindow = None;
            event.time = CurrentTime;
            event.x = 1;
            event.y = 1;
            event.x_root = 1;
            event.y_root = 1;
            event.same_screen = True;
            event.type = KeyPress;
            event.state = 0;
            event.keycode = XKeysymToKeycode(dpy, c);
            SendEvent(&event, true);
            event.type = KeyRelease;
            SendEvent(&event, false);
        }
        XCloseDisplay(dpy);
    }

    usleep(20);
    return true;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Forward declaration
int InitComPort(const char *port);
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: bckf serial_port\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int port = InitComPort(argv[1]);
    if (port == -1)
        return 1;

    while (true)
    {
        char buf[30];
        ssize_t res = read(port, buf, 30);
        if (res > 0)
        {
            for (ssize_t i=0; i<res; ++i)
            {
                int c = buf[i];
                printf("Received char: 0x%02x\n", c);
                if (c >= '0' && c <= '9' || c >= 0x08 && c <= 0x1b)
                    if (!sendChar(c))   // called from console?
                        break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int InitComPort(const char *port)
{
    int c, res;
    struct termios newtio;
    struct termios oldtio;

    // Open modem device for reading and writing and not as controlling tty
    // because we don't want to get killed if linenoise sends CTRL-C.
    int fdSerial = open(port, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY );
    if (fdSerial < 0)
    {
        printf(0, "Error opening port: %s\n%s", port, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    tcgetattr(fdSerial,&oldtio); // save current port settings
    memset(&newtio, 0, sizeof(newtio));
    newtio.c_cflag = B9600 | CS8 | CLOCAL | CREAD;                  // CREAD   : enable receiving characters
                                                                    // CS8     : character size 8
                                                                    // CLOCAL  : Ignore modem control lines
    newtio.c_iflag = IGNPAR;                                        // IGNPAR  : ignore bytes with parity errors
    newtio.c_oflag = 0;                                             // 0       : raw output (no echo, non-canonical)
    //newtio.c_cc[VTIME]    = timeout;                              // 10=1sec : inter-character timer (deciseconds)
    newtio.c_cc[VMIN]     = 1;                                      // 50      : blocking read until 50 chars received
    tcflush(fdSerial, TCIOFLUSH);                                   // clear the line and...
    tcsetattr(fdSerial,TCSANOW,&newtio);                            // ...activate new settings for the port
    return fdSerial;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem in your code is that you open the display every time with XOpenDisplay(...). Every call to XOpenDisplay creates a new protocol context. You should open the display only once, and always use the same display handle when you send the events. Within the context of a single display handle, the events are guaranteed to remain ordered.

Initialize the display once, e.g. in main(...), before you start to call sendChar(...), and always use the same Display pointer. Close the Display only when you are done, like you do with the Com port.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the original problem now (which is strange), so I cannot be sure that this change fixes it. But, thanks, I'll try it as soon the problem arises again.

Comment: In general, XOpenDisplay(...) opens a new socket. It depends on the state of your X server how it handles requests coming via different sockets, so the problem might come and go. But definitely it is an "error" in the program that you call XOpenDisplay(...) many times; usually you call it just once.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try forcing the timestamp to increment by one for each? That should tell the X server that the events are spread through time, but it also means it bottlenecks your scanner to about 142 scans/second. That sounds okay though, assuming humans are involved in its use.

Comment: As you can see in the code, I do set the CurrentTime for each character. Do you imply that my code executes so fast and multiple characters get the same timestamp? That could explain why it only makes problems on fast machines. Now, which timestamp should I set? A past or a future one?